# Initial parameter of servlet deployed to IBM Portal Server cannot be found

Tags: servlets, initialization, websphere, portal

I have defined a set of initial parameter for my servlet in web.xml file. I have deployed that servlet to a IBM Portal Server v6.1. I can read those parameters in the "Initialize parameters for servlets" page in WAS admin console. However I when I try to fetch those parameters in my code I got null. The following code will print out "number of init paras: 0"

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
  super.init();
  ServletContext c = getServletContext();
    for (Enumeration e = c.getInitParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String s = (String)e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(">>>>>>" + s);
    ++i;
  }
  System.out.println("number of init params: " + i);
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here I got the answer:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
  super.init();
  // ServletContext c = getServletContext(); --ServletContext should be ServletConfig
  ServletConfig c = getServletConfig();
  for (Enumeration e = c.getInitParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String s = (String)e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(">>>>>>" + s);
    ++i;
  }
  System.out.println("number of init params: " + i);
}
```